# How to get Live video stream from Epiphan to VLC player?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc

Is there any way to get the live stream from the Epiphan device using Epiphan SDK to play the same in VLC or ffplay?

Using EPIPHAN SDK, I am able to grab the frames and also their SDK provides a way to convert the frames to GUI but i am not able to find a way to get the live stream of video.

Does ffmpeg lib provide a way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

NitinG,
You don't need SDK itself for that. Epiphan driver already exposes the device via DirectShow/V4Lx interfaces (depending on the OS). It basically looks like a camera for VLC or ffmpeg. Start VLC and go to "Media"->"Open Capture Devices".

You need SDK only if you want to have programmatic access to more advanced, low level features that are difficult to expose over DirectShow or V4Lx interfaces.

Cheers.

Comment: i agree, I was able to do with ffplay and VLC but yes I have to do it programmatic as well and I am not able to find any documentation for the SDK and the Epiphan don't have any as well..